# Heatmap with colour each for multiple ranges of values in plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a annotated heatmap using plotly in the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9ds7mryr/5/

My intention is to have three colours for three individual ranges

```
<0.75 #FFA500
>0.75 and <0.90 rgb(255,0,0)
>0.90 #F0E7E7
```

However, right now I get the same colour for some of the values even though they are different if slightly.

How can I ensure values of the same range have the same colour?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `colorscale` to

```
[
  [0, '#FFA500'],
  [0.1, '#FFA500'],
  [0.2, '#FFA500'],
  [0.3, '#FFA500'],
  [0.4, '#FFA500'],
  [0.74,'#FFA500'],
  [0.75, 'rgb(255,0,0)'],
  [0.89, 'rgb(255,0,0)'],
  [0.90, '#F0E7E7'],
  [0.95, '#F0E7E7'],
  [1, '#F0E7E7']
]
```

The [`colorscale`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#heatmap-colorscale) needs to be between 0 and 1, i.e. your values will be automatically normalized to be between those values. Since your values start higher than 0 and lower than 1 they will be shifted. You can change this behavior with `zmin` and `zmax`.

```js
var xValues = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'max', 'min'];

var yValues = ['W'];

var zValues = [
  [0.80, 0.110, 0.220, 0.74, 0.90, 1, 0]
];

var colorscaleValue = [
  [0, '#FFA500'],
  [0.1, '#FFA500'],
  [0.2, '#FFA500'],
  [0.3, '#FFA500'],
  [0.4, '#FFA500'],
  [0.74,'#FFA500'],
  [0.75, 'rgb(255,0,0)'],
  [0.89, 'rgb(255,0,0)'],
  [0.90, '#F0E7E7'],
  [0.95, '#F0E7E7'],
  [1, '#F0E7E7']
];



var data = [{
  x: xValues,
  y: yValues,
  z: zValues,
  type: 'heatmap',
  colorscale: colorscaleValue,
  showscale: true,
}];

var layout = {
  title: 'Annotated Heatmap',
  annotations: [],
  xaxis: {
    ticks: '',
    side: 'top'
  },
  yaxis: {
    ticks: '',
    ticksuffix: ' ',
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    autosize: true
  }
};


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
```